# Connecting 2 identical led RGBW controllers with 12V led strips same length into a 24V Power supply

Tags: power-supply, led-strip, 12v, rgb, 24v

Ok, some bad decisions took place and now i am stuck with no money and:

1. 24V 8.33A  power supply with 2 channels.
2. Magic Home 5V-12V-24V RGBW wifi Controller 192W max (got them from [here](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/33035745736.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.34604c4dzynuET))
3. 15m of 12V 5050 RGBW Led strips with 5.76W/m. (got them from [here](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32622948477.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.34604c4dzynuET))

And now i have to make them my main living room lighting (total space of 5m x 6m ).

I was thinking about connecting the 2 controllers in parallel to each other having exactly the same length of leds attacked to each of them, and controlling them with google home thus, making them open only at the same time, creating a "voltage divider".

Like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGVUx0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My question now is:

1. Is this safe?
2. Is this the best solution considering i cant afford a big 12V supply?

Comment: Start saving is my advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No, not safe. As soon as one controller consumes different amount of current, there will be imbalance between the voltages.
2. It is not a solution at all. Connecting like that may damage something.